# How to return a List from jparsec without using .between()

Tags: java, parsing, jparsec

I'm working on a simple parser using the JParsec library and want to parse the following:

```
some, list, of, things
```

This is easily done with with `parser.sepBy(Scanners.isChar(',')` but fails to parse in a larger document unless I wrap it inside a `between`.

Ultimately I'm wanting to parse something along the lines of:

```
implements some.java.Interface, some.other.Interface {
  ...
}
```

However I can't find a magic combination to say "sepBy X until (but not consuming Y)" or even "sepBy X until failure".

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more or less complete Java parser in the examples directory which implements that kind of stuff. The trick is to include your parser for a list of things inside a sequence, or combined with next() with another parSer for the body between curly braces, assuming curly braces cannot occur within your list's elements.

Here is the `classDef` method from `org.codehaus.jparsec.examples.java.parser.DeclarationParser`:

```
 static Parser<Declaration> classDef(Parser<Modifier> mod, Parser<Member> member) {
   return curry(ClassDef.class).sequence(
       mod.many(), term("class"), Terminals.Identifier.PARSER, TYPE_PARAMETERS.optional(),
       term("extends").next(ELEMENT_TYPE_LITERAL).optional(),
       term("implements").next(ELEMENT_TYPE_LITERAL.sepBy1(term(","))).optional(),
       body(member));
 }
```

The part you are interested in is `term("implements").next(ELEMENT_TYPE_LITERAL.sepBy1(term(","))).optional()`. Notice this fragment is an optional part of a *sequence* of parsers whose returned elements are used to create a `ClassDef` AST object.

Comment: Cheers! I think the main thing I've been missing is using term(). I'm not using tokens or anything either, which may also be hindering things a little. Will give it shot!

Comment: The use of term is not mandatory, it's just a way to build a token parser with built in support from parsec (operators, deliniters) instead of using directly strings.